# Problema con menu de opciones en Python

Tags: python, while

Este es un sistema para una hipotetica inscripcion de alumnos. Primero se deben colocar los datos del alumno y luego se hace la inscricion. Aqui solo procesamos la primera marte, otras funciones hacen lo de la inscripcion.
El problema es q por alguna razon, justo al principio del menu, el while se repite infinitamente, sin importar si la condicion se cumple o no.

Meto este dato dentro del rango pero aun asi, el programa no continua, sino q continua exigiendome el dato.

```
def menu():
        """[Menu para escoger la opcion en cuestion]
        """
        centinela = 0
        nombre = ""
        apellido = ""
        datos = []

        print("""
        1-Ingresar datos.
        2-Salir
        """)
        while centinela not in [1,2]:
            centinela = input("Que quieres hacer?: ")#Este es el primer dato que pide
            if centinela == 1:
                nombre = input("Nombre del alumno: ")
                apellido = input("Apellido del alumno: ")
                while type(ci) is not int or float:
                    ci = input("Cedula del ingresado: ")#Validar con expresiones regulares
                    if ci == "salir":
                        os.sys.exit()
                    os.sys("cls")

                while rentaLiquida not in ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]:
                    print("""
                    ESCOJA SU RENTA LIQUIDA:
                    a- 25000
                    b- 30000
                    c- 40000
                    d- 50000
                    """)
                    rentaLiquida = input("Alija su opción: ")
                if rentaLiquida == "a":
                    rentaLiquida = 25000
                elif rentaLiquida == "b":
                    rentaLiquida = 30000
                elif rentaLiquida == "c":
                    rentaLiquida = 40000
                elif rentaLiquida == "d":
                    rentaLiquida = 50000
                elif rentaLiquida == "e":
                    os.sys.exit() 
                os.sys("cls")

                while patrimonio not in ["a","b","c","d", "e"]:
                    print("""
                    ESCOJA SU PATRIMONIO:
                    a- 100000
                    b- 200000
                    c- 250000
                    d- 300000
                    e- Salir
                    """)
                    patrimonio = input("Alija su opción: ")
                if patrimonio == "a":
                    patrimonio = 100000
                elif patrimonio == "b":
                    patrimonio = 200000
                elif patrimonio == "c":
                    patrimonio = 250000
                elif patrimonio == "d":
                    patrimonio = 300000
                elif patrimonio == "e":
                    os.sys.exit()



            elif centinela == 2:
                os.sys.exit()
        return datos[nombre, apellido, ci, rentaLiquida, patrimonio]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
centinela = input("Que quieres hacer?: ")#Este es el primer dato que pide
if centinela == 1:
```

La función `input` devuelve un string. Si tecleas "1", retorna un "1" (caracter), no un 1 (entero).

Tienes que usar `int` para hacer la conversión:

```
centinela = int(input("Que quieres hacer?: "))
if centinela == 1:
```

Y aplicar la misma lógica donde corresponda.